# C++ MP3,WAV and ACC (Low Level) Decoder?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, codeblocks, decoder

I have searched before saying this question but i cannot find any decent decorder.

I'm using codeblocks under gcc/linux and i need to use QT and **C++** for programming.

The ideal would be a LGPL, **low-level** library well documented, that reproduces at **least 24 bits**. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **libavcodec** from ffmpeg:
http://libav.org/doxygen/master/index.html

It is used in MPlayer and in VLC as the decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into SOX?  I believe it can process the file formats that you mentioned, as well as raw data files consisting of sample values in txt format.  See http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage